# What was the argument between pirates and Yondu?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

Near the beginning of Guardians of the Galaxy 2, Yondu is in an argument on a snowy world and his crew is exiled from the "family". I was quite confused watching the scene unfold, as if I had forgotten some important scenes from the first movie.

What was the argument about? Why was Yondu outcast? Was there anything from the first movie that ties into this that I should be remembering?

Comment: They said "for dealing in children" (or something along those lines)... presumably they didn't like the fact that Yondu was tracking down children and delivering them over to Ego.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What was the argument about?**

Argument was about Yandu breaking the Ravagers code in past. Here is the full conversation:

> **Yondu:** Are you gonna listen to what I got to say?
>   **Stakar Ogord:** I don't got to listen to nothing, you betrayed the code! > Ravagers don't deal in kids!
>   **Yondu:** I told you before, I didn't know what was going on!
>   **Stakar Ogord:** You didn't know, because you didn't want to know, because it made you rich! - [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/quotes?item=qt3396789)

**Why was Yondu outcast?**

For the same reason, "breaking the Ravagers code". Yando was stealing Ego's kids for him and Peter was one of those kids too which he didn't delivered to Ego. [Here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74003/did-yondu-know-what-was-happening-to-the-children-he-delivered) is a related question to that.

**Was there anything from the first movie that ties into this that I should be remembering?**

Not much, Stakar Ogord's character appeared for the first time and Ravager's code and other Ravagers came in MCU for the first time. But Yando did mentioned about not delivering Peter in first film:

> **Kraglin:** Yeah, Quill turned out okay. It's probably good we didn't deliver him to his dad like we was hired to do.
>   **Yondu Udonta:** Yeah, that guy was a jackass. [src](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy)

<sub>Note: Stakar is a important character form Marvel comics and might play important role in future.</sub>

Comment: Fun fact: Stakar and his team which appear in post credits were actually the original Guardians of the Galaxy. Plus, one of the members (mainframe) was voiced by Miley Cyrus.